# Saving the total count from entries in a column with Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Ok so this should be simple but I'm having the hardest time trying to do what I need done. (I'm still fairly new to python).

What I'm trying to do: I want to run a Python script with Pandas through a column searching for values higher than 0.02. IF the script finds an entry higher than 0.02, it saves it as a 1 and adds each one after that as a 1 and not its reported value. The idea is to compare how many entries are above 0.02 with the total count of the column and get a percentage value.

```
import pandas

# Need to establish what file to run, then create headers for the 
columns to pull for later computing
df = pandas.read_csv('random.csv', 
names=['Name', 'some', 'thing', 'Value', 'Dots', 'Average', 'Average2', 
'Accuracy', 'run'])

# Begin with the count of how many lines there are to start
print('Checking the my wizardry...\n')

count_row = df.shape[0]

print('Total count for this file is: ' + str(count_row))


bad = 0
# Loop through Accuracy Column to compute percentage of bad entries
for i in df['Accuracy']: 
  if i > 0.02:
    print(i)
```

Sample Output:

```
Checking the my wizardry...
Total count for this file is: 279
0.357
0.353
0.341
0.337
0.332
0.325
0.325
0.32
0.31
0.306
0.306
0.297
...
```

This script is something I'm using for work to automate a process that I use to do manually and figured this would be great for a fun project.

Comment: 0.01 or 0.02? (Your example is inconsistent.) Add a sample datraframe and the expected output to your post.

Comment: Yes, I can see that now. Edited!

Comment: Is the percentage the only value that is of interest to you? Do you really need the actual "large" values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am not mistaken you just want to divide the number of values that are greater than 0.02 by the total number of values in the column.

```
df

   Accuracy
0     0.005
1     0.020
2     0.034
3     0.560

float(df.query('Accuracy > 0.02').count() / df.Accuracy.count())

0.5
```

Or

```
(df['Accuracy'] > 0.02).sum() / df['Accuracy'].count()

0.5
```

Comment: This absolutely worked! I don't know why I was so fixated on an if/else statement to get the result I wanted.

Comment: if you're looping through a `pandas` column using typical python loops you are more than likely doing something wrong, many of the operations have ways to do them specific to pandas